# masm call procedure access violation

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, irvine32

So I am working on an assignment in assembly to generate a fibonacci sequence. I've written the code successfully in the main procedure but when I try to wrap it in it's own procedure and call that procedure I run into an access violation error. Here's my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
array DWORD 47 DUP(?)

.code
main proc
mov esi, OFFSET array

call generate_fibonacci

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp

generate_fibonacci PROC

mov DWORD PTR [esi], 1h
add esi, 4
mov DWORD PTR [esi], 1h
push [esi]
push [esi - 4]
add esi, 4
mov ecx, 45
L1: 
pop eax
pop ebx
add eax, ebx
mov DWORD PTR [esi], eax
add esi, 4
push [esi - 4]
push [esi - 8]
loop L1
ret

generate_fibonacci ENDP

end main
```

The error looks like this: "Exception thrown at *some memory location* in Project...: Access violation executing location *same memory location*.

I noticed that the memory location listed in the error message was being loaded onto the EIP register when the call generate_fibonacci instruction is executed. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why do you use the stack at all in this non-recursive solution? Why not simply write: `mov eax,[esi-4]` `mov ebx,[esi]` ?

Comment: BTW, passing the first arg in `esi` is not the normal calling convention for 32bit.  It's ok that main doesn't save its caller's value of esi, because it never returns.  (You're calling `ExitProcess` instead.)  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to info about calling conventions.

Comment: Part of the assignment was to utilize push and pop instructions along with creating and calling a procedure. I know, it's weird, I initially was able to write the code without either of those things.

Answer (score 3):

The pushes and pops in your `PROC` are not balanced.

Before loop `L1:` you make 2 pushes. Within the loop `L1:` you make 2 pops and 2 pushes. When loop `L1:` ends, that leaves 2 items still on the stack when `ret` attempts to pull off the return address. So the code tries to resume execution somewhere that causes an access violation.

Please add two lines of code before the `ret` instruction to clean up the stack

```
pop eax
pop eax
ret
```

If the same code worked when it was in `main`, it worked because `main` does not end with `ret`.

**EDIT.** You could simplify it considerably by keeping the recent terms in registers. The last three terms will be in `eax`, `ebx`, `edx`.

```
generate_fibonacci PROC

    mov     eax, 1                  ;init first two terms
    mov     DWORD PTR [esi], eax    ;store first two terms
    add     esi, 4
    mov     DWORD PTR [esi], eax
    add     esi, 4

    mov     ebx, eax
    mov     ecx, 45                 ;init loop count
L1: 
    mov     edx, ebx                ;move terms along
    mov     ebx, eax
    add     eax, edx                ;sum last two terms
    mov     DWORD PTR [esi], eax
    add     esi, 4
    loop    L1
    ret

generate_fibonacci ENDP
```

Comment: Ahh no wonder that portion of my code bothered me too  but had no idea that it was actually causing an issue since it ran fine when it was in the main. Thanks!!